# How to add another condition to Sudoku puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, backtracking

I have just start coding with python since fall. So i am not a professional python coder.
I have started to code a Sudoku program. And fortunately at last I could have come up with this code:

```
def isValid(num, x, y):
    for i in range(9):
        if board[i][y] == num:
            return False
        if board[x][i] == num:
            return False
    row = x - x % 3
    col = y - y % 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i + row][j + col] == num:
                return False
    return True
def solve(remaining):
    if remaining == 0:
        return True
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if board[i][j] != 0:
                continue
            for num in range(1, 10):
                if isValid(num, i, j):
                    board[i][j] = num
                    if solve(remaining - 1):
                        return True
                    board[i][j] = 0
            return False
    return False
def pp():
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            print(board[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    print()
board = []
remaining = 0
for i in range(9):
    a=input()
    a=a.split()
    a = list(map(int, a))
    for j in a:
        if j == 0:
            remaining += 1
    board.append(a)
solve(remaining)
pp()
```

For instance I give such an input to it:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 4
0 0 0 0 5 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 6 5 0 0
0 7 0 3 0 0 0 8 0
0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0
5 8 0 0 0 0 9 0 0
6 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And this is my output:

```
7 4 9 2 3 8 6 1 5 
1 5 2 6 9 7 8 3 4 
8 3 6 4 5 1 2 7 9 
2 1 8 9 7 6 5 4 3 
9 7 5 3 2 4 1 8 6 
4 6 3 8 1 5 7 9 2 
3 2 1 5 8 9 4 6 7 
5 8 4 7 6 3 9 2 1 
6 9 7 1 4 2 3 5 8
```

Now I intend to add a new condition to this Sudoku which is can do this process for 4 more 3*3 boxes in the board like this (which is named Hyper-Sudoku):

That for my puzzle it returns:

```
9 4 6 8 3 2 7 1 5
1 5 2 6 9 7 8 3 4
7 3 8 4 5 1 2 9 6
8 1 9 7 2 6 5 4 3
4 7 5 3 1 9 6 8 2
2 6 3 5 4 8 1 7 9
3 2 7 9 8 5 4 6 1
5 8 4 1 6 3 9 2 7
6 9 1 2 7 4 3 5 8
```

Is there any way to add this option to my Sudoku or not, I have to change my whole algorithm?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your program looks great. Since you separated your `isValid` and `solve` functions it makes adding the change easier. All you will need to is modify the `isValid` function.

```
def isValid(num, x, y):
    # row and column check
    for i in range(9):
        if board[i][y] == num:
            return False
        if board[x][i] == num:
            return False

    # 3x3 tile check
    row = x - x % 3
    col = y - y % 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i + row][j + col] == num:
                return False

    # Hypersudoku check
    if x not in [0, 4, 8] and y not in [0, 4, 8]:
        row = 1 if x < 4 else 5
        col = 1 if y < 4 else 5
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if board[i + row][j + col] == num:
                     return False

    return True
```